# Object properties doesn't update from function

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, object

I have an global declared empty object. Inside function **saveBookmarks** i'm trying to add some values to object. But outside of function, object **usersBookmarks** doesn't save values. What is the problem and how to fix this? Thank you

```
var usersBookmarks = {};

$('#upload').click(function () {
    chrome.bookmarks.getTree(function (bookmarks) {
        saveBookmarks(bookmarks);
    });

    var noChildren = false;

    function saveBookmarks(bookmarks) {
        if (noChildren === false) {
            bookmarks.forEach(function (bookmark) {
                if (bookmark.children) {
                    saveBookmarks(bookmark.children);
                } else {
                    noChildren = true;
                    usersBookmarks.user.bookmarks = {
                        "id" : bookmark.id,
                        "title" : bookmark.title,
                        "dateAdded" : bookmark.dateAdded
                    };
                }
            });
        }
    } //end of saveBookmarks function
    document.getElementById('root').innerHTML = usersBookmarks;
});
```

Comment: How do you reason that "outside of function [it] doesn't save changes"? Because of `...innerHTML = usersBookmarks`? Well… that just happens once while the object is still empty. It won't update if and when you actually add something to the object.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, i have solved this problem. I just wrote function that i need inside **if** statement

Answer (score 0):

You have to use push method.multiple item should be stored in array not in object

```
usersBookmarks.user.bookmarks.push( {
        "id": bookmark.id,
        "title": bookmark.title,
        "dateAdded": bookmark.dateAdded
      });
```